# Eclipce BIRT preview error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Please help!
I'm creating report in BIRT Eclipce Designer. Database is MySQL server. When I click to Preview in Eclipse appears an error: 
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /viewer/run. Reason:

```
Plug-in org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer was unable to load class org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.
```

I think its plugin error, but I don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your birt installation miss that class file for report preview, try reinstalling again birt plugin and all of its components .